# Is "Let her go. Right now!" a request?

Tags: word-choice

> "Let her go. Right now!"
>
> The man just laughed at his **request**.

Is *request* the most appropriate word to use here?

Comment: It's a _command_ rather than a request (which would be something like 'Please let her go.').

Comment: Idiomatically, ***plea[ding][s]*** would be much better than ***request*** here. Unless you want to emphasise the "command" format (even though contextually there's obviously no chance of that command being obeyed, so it's not a typical example).

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be more accurately described as a "command" or "order" rather than a request.  "Request" implies that you are asking somebody to do something instead of telling them to do it.

However, that doesn't mean your sentence is wrong.  You could certainly say "The man just laughed at his request" to imply that the man chose to interpret the statement (which was clearly intended as a command) as if it was only a request instead.  This can add a feeling of extra dismissiveness, along the lines of "You don't get to give me orders.  I've considered your *request*, and rejected it."

So actually your example there seems quite natural, but definitely emphasizes that the second person did not accept the command as being a valid command.